# PHP gmdate returns time one hour behind

Tags: php

I have this code

```
if (date_default_timezone_get()) {
    echo 'date_default_timezone_set: ' . date_default_timezone_get() . '<br />';
}

echo 'time: ' .date('Y-m-d H:i:s'). '<br />';


if (ini_get('date.timezone')) {
    echo 'date.timezone: ' . ini_get('date.timezone'). '<br />';
}

echo 'time: ' .gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time()). '<br />';
```

and this is the output I get

```
date_default_timezone_set: Europe/London
time: 2016-03-29 21:26:41
date.timezone: Europe/London
time: 2016-03-29T20:26:41.000Z
```

So my php.ini is set to London, and still GMT is one hour behind.
No matter what I do, gmdate is always the same time, which is wrong, because accourding to world clock, GMT time now is 19:26.

I am running on localhost.
My local time & machine time while running the code was 22:26.
I tried changing to these timezones in the php.ini:

- Asia/Kuwait - GMT+4
- Asia/Jerusalem - GMT+3
- Europe/Berlin - GMT+1
- Europe/London - 0

nothing helps. Any ideas?

**UPDATE & SOLUTION**

As suggested in the comments, the issue is related to daylight saving. The hour on my computer is set to the correct local time in my country. However, I think they changed the date the time was moved, it was changed about 1 week ago, and checking on my windows control panel it was only expecting it on Apr 1st.

The only thing that worked for me was changing the timezone on my computer to a different timezone. Not a great solution, and I will probably need to change again next week, but it works for now..

To change the timezone on windows this is what I did:
1) Open Date and Time by clicking the Start button , clicking Control Panel, clicking Clock, Language, and Region, and then clicking Date and Time.
2) Change time zone -> change time zone.
3) Adjust the time.

Answer (score 0):

It looks correct :)

gmdate does not take *daylight savings* into account.

That the time is one hour behind seems to confirm that.

The *date* function appears to be adjusting itself - try to use that instead.

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php - although I suspect that you already have.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing due to time change? You could change the time manually or use an API like this one :http://www.timeapi.org/.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What jacmoe said is correct. The [Greenwich Mean Time](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/) site exhibits the same behavior as the `gmdate()` and `date()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, gmdate() can not directly take daylight saving into account, it's a really rather unuseful function.  The cleanest way to do this is using the normal date function, setting your timezone before hand, for example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
echo time();
```